# in Ubuntu why don't I see a specific version in usr/bin of python when I download it?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, virtualenv

Hi I'm trying to get a specific version of python working in a virtualenv

I tried these solutions:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/682869/how-do-i-install-a-different-python-version-using-apt-get

I didn't do the compiling answers because it looked like doing that was going to get rid of my "old" newer version of python.

So I'm mostly concerned with the first answer.  I did this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.3
```

it seemed to work out ok although I didn't get a "python3.3 is installed message" or however it's supposed to look:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'python3-3parclient' for regex 'python3.3'
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python3-dnspython python3-eventlet python3-greenlet
Suggested packages:
  python-eventlet-doc python-greenlet-doc python-greenlet-dev
  python3-greenlet-dbg
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3-3parclient python3-dnspython python3-eventlet python3-greenlet
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
Need to get 316 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,867 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 python3-greenlet amd64 0.4.15-4.1 [15.7 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 python3-dnspython all 1.16.0-1build1 [89.1 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 python3-eventlet all 0.25.1-2ubuntu1 [154 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 python3-3parclient all 4.2.11-0ubuntu1 [57.4 kB]
Fetched 316 kB in 0s (1,007 kB/s)            
Selecting previously unselected package python3-greenlet.
(Reading database ... 212769 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-greenlet_0.4.15-4.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-greenlet (0.4.15-4.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-dnspython.
Preparing to unpack .../python3-dnspython_1.16.0-1build1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-dnspython (1.16.0-1build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-eventlet.
Preparing to unpack .../python3-eventlet_0.25.1-2ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-eventlet (0.25.1-2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-3parclient.
Preparing to unpack .../python3-3parclient_4.2.11-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-3parclient (4.2.11-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python3-greenlet (0.4.15-4.1) ...
Setting up python3-dnspython (1.16.0-1build1) ...
Setting up python3-eventlet (0.25.1-2ubuntu1) ...
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/eventlet/db_pool.py:78: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if self.max_age is 0 or self.max_idle is 0:
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/eventlet/db_pool.py:78: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if self.max_age is 0 or self.max_idle is 0:
Setting up python3-3parclient (4.2.11-0ubuntu1) ...
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/hpe3parclient/http.py:278: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if self.tries is 0:
```

After this was done, I expected python 3.3 to be available in usr/bin so I could set up a `virtualenv` with it, but it's not.  Is there a step I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: What are the outputs of `which python` and `ls -lrt /usr/bin/python`

Comment: @lllrnr101: `which python` doesn't give me anything and `ls -lrt /usr/bin/python` gives me `No such file or directory`  when I do `ls /usr/bin/python*` I get:

Comment: ```/usr/bin/python2    /usr/bin/python3.8         /usr/bin/python3-futurize
/usr/bin/python2.7  /usr/bin/python3.8-config  /usr/bin/python3-pasteurize
/usr/bin/python3    /usr/bin/python3-config
``` @lllrnr101

Comment: `/usr/bin/python3`, `usr/bin/python2`, are symlinks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that 3.3 doesn't work with my ubuntu 20.04.  I thought because my python2.7 worked I could just move up to 3.3 no problem.  I guess the 2.7 only is there because it was leftover from an older ubuntu.

Anyways, python3.5 worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using ubuntu 20.04

Unfortunately, without funding I can't provide packages for python<3.5 on 20.04 because those versions never received the libssl1.1 patches upstream.  I could patch them myself but that's a lot of work I can't rationalize doing for free.  So on 20.04 you'll need to use python3.5+

The reason "something" installed was `apt-get` """helpfully""" normalized your package name to something completely unrelated:

```
Note, selecting 'python3-3parclient' for regex 'python3.3'
```

---

disclaimer: I maintain deadsnakes